# Laravel Запрос с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.6

Допустим есть таблица пользователей, у которых есть два поля: месяц и год рождения. Необходимо сделать выборку: показать пользователей в диапазоне декабрь 2017 по январь 2018.
Например: $users = User::query()->where('month', '>=', 12)->where('year', '>=', 2017)->where('month', '<=', 1)->where('year', '<=', 2018)->get(); но не понятно, как объединить, чтобы условия >=12 и >=2017 выполнялись одновременно.
Т.е. сначала нашел записи, которые входят в условие >=12 and >=2017, а потом <=1 and <=2018.

Comment: Преобразовать в строку формата `YYYYMM`, а потом тупо `BETWEEN '201712' AND '201801'`. Ну или числом, `WHERE year*100+month BETWEEN 201712 AND 201801` (впрочем, множить можно и на 12...).

Comment: @Akina только у меня месяц и год в разных полях, если использовать whereBetween, то первым параметром идет поле, а затем диапазон, как в таком случае быть?

Comment: `WHERE (поле или выражение) BETWEEN (нижняя граница) AND (верхняя граница)` В данном случае будет использоваться выражение, которое вычисляется на основании значений двух разных полей - всё ровно.

Comment: @Akina пробовал так написать $users->whereBetween(201712, [201712, 201804]); если посмотреть sql, то получается Where `201712` BETWEEN 201712
  AND 201804 и ругается, что не знает поля `201712`

Comment: Потому что `201712` - это не имя поля, а некий литерал (значение). И вместо него должно быть вычисляющее выражение. И, соответственно, DB::Raw.

Comment: @Akina написал $users->whereBetween(\DB::raw('year*100+month'), [201712, 201804]); работает. А с помощью where можно сделать, чтобы проверялось не по одному полю, а сразу два?

Comment: *А с помощью where можно сделать, чтобы проверялось не по одному полю, а сразу два?* Да хоть десять. Документацию смотреть не пробовал? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses, раздел Parameter Grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант решения проблемы можно использовать whereRaw: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions